# Lookup Table to Produce Extracted Lists

Tags: list-manipulation

My code below extracts the correct lists, but within each list the output jumbles the order of the elements when the code reads a number like "3" or "3.1" or E (which it sees as Euler's "e") or (A-B0) which it sees as a difference.

I'm looking for the elements in the extracted lists to be in the same order as they appear in the set defined by m and for all elements to be treated as text and not a number or numerical difference. For example, when the Case extracts (say) N6102 it should show N6102, qaw - E (absb) which is the original element order in the m matrix.

```
ClearAll;
m = {{N6101, WES QWA 3 (zxs)}, {N6102, qaw - E (absb)}, {N6424, 
    MIP 3.1 (dssa)}, {N6602, HGS 136.5 (tgf)}, {N6603, 
    Mok (iop)}, {N6604, KG NEK (A - B0)}};
index = Association[(#[[2]] -> #[[1]]) & /@ 
    Table[{i, m[[i, 1]]}, {i, 1, Length[m]}]];
m[[index /@ {N6102, N6604, N6424}]];
Cases[m, {N6102 | N6604 | N6424, __}];
TableForm[%]
```

Comment: If elements are not text, you can force them to be a text: `m1 = Map[ToString, m, {2}]` and then use `m1`. Further possible optimization: `index = AssociationThread[m1[[All, 1]] -> Range[Length[m1]]]` and your `m[[index /@ ...]]` can be written as `m1[[Values@index]]`.

Comment: thank you but this doesn't seem to work

Comment: Take a look at `FullForm@m` and you will see why the order has changed. How was this list constructed? To preserve order the second element has to be a string not the product of symbols. `m = {{N6101, "WES QWA 3 (zxs)"}, {N6102, "qaw-E (absb)"}, ...`

Comment: Rohit Namjoshi: very good...thank you! ... prg